# I'm getting continuous blob files in blob storage. I have to load in Databricks and put in Azure SQL DB. Data factory for orchestrating this pipeline

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I receive data continuously in blob storage. I have initially 5 blob files in the blob storage I'm able to load from blob to Azure SQL DB using Databricks and automated it using Data factory, But the problem is when newer files come in blob storage the databricks loads these files along with older files and sends it into Azure SQL DB. I don't want these old files, every time I want only the newer one's, so that same data is not loaded again and again in the Azure SQL DB.

Comment: Use blob trigger to bind a callback function as explained here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=javascript#trigger

Comment: This link gives you an idea about how to use Event Grid to trigger web endpoints in response to events in Blob Storage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

Comment: Hey @ArunSelin I will be using databricks. Any spark scala code I can execute in databricks notebook is appreciated.

Comment: @ArunSelin Im using databricks for transformation of blob data and put it into SQL db. But the problem is when It is automated using ADF i can see the old blob data loaded into the sql again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is to simply archive the file that you just read into a new folder name it `archiveFolder`. Say, your databricks is reading from the following directory:

```
mnt
  sourceFolder
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    file3.txt
```

You run your code, you ingested the files and loaded them in SQL server. Then what you can simply do is to archive these files (move them from the `sourceFolder` into `archiveFolder`. This can simply be done in databricks using the following command

```
dbutils.fs.mv(sourcefilePath, archiveFilePath, True)
```

So, next time your code runs, you will only have the new files in your `sourceFolder`.